# how to fix error 'int' object has no attribute 'text' when trying to make a word cloud image

Tags: python, word-cloud

How can I fix this error, I'm trying to combine text and create a word cloud image.

```
from os import path 
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator

text = [] 
cb = cbData #text dataset
tc = 0
for t in cb.text:
    text.append(t)
    tc += 1

all_text = " ".join(t for t in text)
print("Total words in all posts: ", len(all_text))
```

this is the error:

```
----> 3 for t in cb.text:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simply telling you that you are trying to use an attribute or method that doesn't exist. I suggest listing the attributes/methods that **do** exist and figuring out what to do from there. This can be done as such:

```
# code that generates variable "cb" (not supplied in post)
print(dir(cb))
```

Now, look at the output and see what method/attribute you should be trying to access. Perhaps it is something as simple as it being `.Text` or `.text()`

Note: the list generated will not tell you if it should be `.text` or `.text()` (the difference being the parenthesis) so if one doesn't work just use the other!